# My login page won't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a log in program, but I can't get it to work.

When I'm running the code and type in the right `Username` and `Password`, it says wrong input.

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title('LoginPage')

gebruikersnaam = 'Donald'
wachtwoord = 'Trump'

lblUsername = tkinter.Label(window,text='Username:')
lblUsername.pack(fill=tkinter.X)

entUsername = tkinter.Entry(window)
entUsername.pack(fill=tkinter.X)

lblPassword = tkinter.Label(window,text='Password:')
lblPassword.pack(fill=tkinter.X)

entPassword = tkinter.Entry(window)
entPassword.pack(fill=tkinter.X)

lblResult = tkinter.Label(window)
lblResult.pack(fil=tkinter.X)

def checkLogin(username,password):

    if str(username) == gebruikersnaam and str(password) == wachtwoord:
        lblResult.configure(text='Login was succesfull')

    else:
        lblResult.configure(text='Username or Password is wrong')

btn = tkinter.Button(window,text='Login',command= lambda    x=entPassword.get(), y=entUsername.get():checkLogin(y,x))

btn.pack(fill=tkinter.X)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now, your code calls `get()` methods as soon as it runs, that's why you are getting empty values and "wrong input".
You need to make `get()` methods run after button click to give user some time to actually enter some values.

So you should pass `Entry`s as parameters and call `get()` methods inside of lambda.

```
btn = tkinter.Button(..., command=lambda x=entUsername, y=entPassword: checkLogin(x.get(), y.get()))
```

**BUT**, I think, instead of `lambda`, you should use a wrapper function, that calls `checkLogin`. Which makes your code easier to read and follow.

```
def wrapperCheck():
    checkLogin(entUsername.get(), entPassword.get())

btn = tkinter.Button(window, text='Login', command=wrapperCheck)
btn.pack(fill=tkinter.X)
```

**EDIT:** Yet, even better approach is (thanks to comment from [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley)), remove parameters from your method and fetch those values inside of it.

```
def checkLogin():
    username = entUsername.get() 
    password = entPassword.get()
    #since get returns string objects you dont need str calls 
    if username == gebruikersnaam and password == wachtwoord:
        lblResult.configure(text='Login was succesfull')
    else:
        lblResult.configure(text='Username or Password is wrong')

    #also you can remove these temp values and directly compare like below
    # entUsername.get() == gebruikersnaam and entPassword.get() == wachtwoord

btn = tkinter.Button(window,text='Login',command= checkLogin)
```

Comment: Wow it works, thank you so much for the fast and fantastic support

Comment: even better is to remove the use of `lambda` altogether. `checkLogin` can easily fetch the values when it is called.

Comment: @Bryan A-ha! No idea why I thought I'd need a wrapper in here. I guess nowhere is safe from brainfart. Thanks. (now I am on mobile, can't edit properly, will edit as soon as I can)

Comment: @SerialCoder Added another approach, which is better than my initial suggestion.